# How Do I Override Body CSS For Whole Page?

Tags: jquery, css

There is a webpage named `index.html` which has all the CSS and JS files. There are already `body` properties like `font-family`, `font-size`, `color`.

I want to add my own CSS to the `body`. I am using jQuery for this, where `response['body_tag']` is a Google font name.

It is not overriding anything at all and I am seeing no changes.

```js
$('body').css({
  "font-family": response['body_tag'] + " !important",
  "font-size": "10px",
  "color": "red",
});
```

Here's the debug console: (Font-size and color is getting cheanged , but font-family doesn't)

there are no errors in console too.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1p5d.png)

Comment: Remove the `!important` flag, it does not work with `css()`. That alone should fix your issue, as inline styling will override anything in an external stylesheet. If it's not working, check the DOM using the browser dev tools to ensure there are no errors in the JS and the styling has been applied. This will also tell you what rules, if any, are overriding yours. Also check that you're added the Google font to the page correctly.

Comment: Try to run your jquery code after the page fully loads by wrapping it into document ready function. https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/